# Problem with loging in chat room

Tags: bug

I have more than twenty reputation points though unable to post messages on chat rooms.Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What happens when you try to post in chat? Are you not able to access the chat room at all, or does it just prevent you from posting messages? Do you get an error message at any point? That information will be useful in narrowing down the problem.

Comment: We've going to need more information than that to have any chance of helping. What operating system and browser are you using (including versions)? Do you have java and javascript turned on? If you get logged out of the main site can you get logged back in (maybe try that on another computer...)? Are you running any browser extensions and/or userscripts that might be interfering? And so on...

Comment: @David Zaslavsky  I can access the chat rooms and even can see even recently posted messages by other members but when I try to write something in my dialogue box and press the send button even then I cant see it anywhere.

Comment: @dmckee I am using Windows7 Ultimate operating system and Google Chrome browser Version 23.0.1271.95 m.Yes java script is tuned on.When I log out of this Physics.stackexchange.com site I find that I can log in again.I had some browser extension turned on but now I turned it off on your saying to debug the problem.

Comment: @dmckee Thanks a lot.I followed every step of your suggestion and finally I can post messages in chat rooms.

Comment: If the problem is extension related you may be able to tell the extension not to work on the `chat.stackexchange.com` domain.